# git credential command not working

Tags: ubuntu, git

When I ran `git credential` command, I get following error:

```
git: 'credential' is not a git command.
```

I correctly configured credential helper with the command

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Do I have to install some other package or command other than git?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html)?

Comment: Yes, and followed the steps... credentials is actually working, it's the command [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-credential.html) that give me the error